# Javascript: Counting the amount of odd numbers

Tags: javascript

Im currently in a javascript crash course and am currently stuck on a block of code. You'll see my commentary within the makeCountingFunction function to see where im logic is going. Can anyone help clarify what is going on?

Included in the code is the teachers commentary.

```
/**
 *
 * Independent Practice: Functions and Callbacks
 *
 * GOALS
 *
 * Your goal in this exercise is for the last line of code in this file to log
 * the number of odd numbers in the array.
 *
 * DIRECTIONS
 *
 * Implement 'makeCountingFunction()', so that it accepts a predicate function
 * as an argument. 'makeCountingFunction()' should return an anonymous function
 * that is able to:
 *
 *  1. iterate through an array and apply the predicate function to each item in
 *     that array,
 *  2. increment a counter based on the result of applying the predicate function
 *     to that item (i.e. does it match what we're looking for?)
 *  3. return the final count.
 *
 * The predicate function 'isOdd()' should accept an individual number as a
 * parameter and return whether or not that number is odd.
 *
 * BONUS 1: Can you write another predicate function that counts evens?
 * BONUS 2: Can you write a function that will return the sum of all numbers?
 *
 */

 function makeCountingFunction(predicate) {     //delcare the function with the parameter predicate
   return function(list) {                     // this returns a second function with the parameter list
      var count = 0;                               // a variable count is declared with the value of 0
      list.forEach(function(item) {               //this states that for each item of the paramter the code needs to return a third function that has a parameter called item
        if (predicate(item)) {                   // this declares that if the parameter predicate.... has something to do with item???? this is where im lost
         count++;                              // the variable count increments by 1
   }
 })
 return count;                           // returns the value of count. This gives up the number of odd integers.
   };
 }

function isOdd(a) {
  return (a % 2) !== 0
}

//     =============================================================================
// The code below should work without modification.
//     =============================================================================

/**
 * The line below should package up 'makeCountingFunction()' and 'isOdd()' into
 * a single function that accepts an array of items as a parameter, iterates
 * through it and returns a count of how many of those items are odd numbers.
 * This new function is being assigned to the variable 'countTheOdds'.
 */

var countTheOdds = makeCountingFunction(isOdd);

/**
 * The final line below calls our new 'countTheOdds()' function and passes in an
 * array of numbers. Once your code is working, the line below should return the
 * number 4.
 */

var oddCount = countTheOdds([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);
console.log('There are ' + oddCount + ' odd numbers.');
// expected output: There are 4 odd numbers.
```

Comment: `list.forEach(function(item) { ` your analysis of this line is incorrect. You are invoking the function on each individual `item` of the `list`, not returning a function.

Comment: I think you need some explanation. so which part is blur?

Comment: I ran your code in the console and it worked fine, what is the issue?

Comment: @AustinSchmidt It seems the problem is `code explain` not `why it's not working`.

Comment: @mortezaT got it. I got the solution code form my teacher, but cant make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

`list.forEach(function(item) {` your analysis of this line is incorrect. You are invoking the function on each individual `item` of the `list`, not returning a function. In the following line where you say your lost, remember that `predicate` is a *function*, in this case if the predicate function returns true for the `item` of the `list`, increment the counter.

It looks like your job is to write the predicate function in question that returns true for odd and false for even, then call the provided function on it, take that returned function and call it with a list of numbers to verify it works:

```
makeCountingFunction(thePredicateYouWrite)([1,2,3,4,5]); // should be 3
```

Comment: Here is a response i received on facebook, might help out.

http://imgur.com/a/8xZpF